# IS there any function to solve five equations with five variables?

Tags: python, sympy

I wrote code to solve five equations with five variables. Once I run the code there is no result and no errors. could anyone fix the problem?

```
### This is the code ###
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

# Define the variables
A,B,C,D,E = symbols('A B C D E')

eq1 = Eq((0.1638*A + 0.1831*B)/(0.16617*C + 0.7679*D) + E ,0.317 )
eq2 = Eq((0.1130*A + 0.1126*B)/(0.4766*C + 0.6885*D) + E ,0.256 )
eq3 = Eq((0.2465*A + 0.2922*B)/(0.4562*C + 0.6312*D) + E ,0.533 )
eq4 = Eq((0.077*A + 0.0594*B)/(0.4849*C + 0.6147*D) + E ,0.177 )
eq5 = Eq((0.0743*A + 0.074*B)/(0.3666*C + 0.5413*D) + E ,0.178 )

# Solve the system of equations
solution = solve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5),(A, B, C, D, E))

# Print the solution
print(solution)
```

Comment: E= variable while 0.317 is the constant

Comment: Do you realize that you have accepted an answer that is not solving your problem?

Comment: @Sercan: calling this system linear is a gross mistake.

Comment: @Sercan Because the equations are non linear. `(a X1 + b X2)` **/** `(c X3 + d X4)` is a non linear function. Could you please have a look at [the excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468107/2749397) from [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21508463/yves-daoust)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not notice the division, this is a mistake, but I dont understand the "gross" part here!

Comment: @Sercan You have not noticed the parentheses too.

Comment: I voted to reopen, because the question is detailed (inasmuch it provides code to reproduce the issue), and is clear (because it clearly states the issue at hand, a formally correct code that produces no answer and no errors). Further, the question has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468107/2749397) that explains the reason of the _apparent_ coding problem (probably no solutions because of the nature of the _mathematical problem_) and propose an alternative. For all these reasons I have voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fractions of the form

```
(a A + b B) / (c C + d D)
```

these four variables are indeterminate to a common factor. Hence you can assign an arbitrary value to any of the unknowns and your system is made of five equations in four unknowns (not five). A priori, it has no solution.

---

In addition, the nonlinearity cannot be removed. If you set an arbitrary value to one of the above four unknowns, you can rewrite the equations in a quadratic form, defining hyperquadrics.

If one of the equations is dependent on the others, or if you just discard one equation, you get a system of four quadratics in four unknowns, with potentially 16 distinct solutions.

Comment: This can be done with `solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4], [A,B,C,E])` which gives two branches of solutions for `A,B,C,E` in terms of `D` which can be chosen arbitrarily.